# Spring boot rabbitmq queue count?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to get a count of the number of messages on my rabbit queue and then purge the queue in my test.  Looking around it seems to suggest I need to use RabbitAdmin to get the counts but unsure how to autowire this into my test?  any ideas?

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

@Value("${queue.producer.name}")
private String queueName;


@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter con= new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    return con;
}

@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, true);
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate r = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    r.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    r.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    return r;
}
```

test class:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestIT {


@Resource
private RabbitAdmin admin;

@Test
public void testQueue() throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    System.out.println(getQueueCount("publish"));

    admin.purgeQueue("publish",true);


}

protected int getQueueCount(final String name) {
    AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk declareOk = admin.getRabbitTemplate().execute(new ChannelCallback<AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk>() {
        public AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk doInRabbit(Channel channel) throws Exception {
            return channel.queueDeclarePassive(name);
        }
    });
    return declareOk.getMessageCount();
}

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the following dependency in your project...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

...then you can leverage the `AmqpAdmin` Bean that's provided by the Spring Boot AutoConfiguration within your Tests.

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RabbitmqTests {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;

    @Test
    public void purgeQueue() throws Exception {
        Integer count = (Integer) amqpAdmin.getQueueProperties("publish").get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT");
        amqpAdmin.purgeQueue("publish", true);
    }

}
```

The example above shows how you can get the message count for a particular queue.